# How do i remove a whole row of a dataframe if one column is 0 or NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (DF) with 4 columns. How do I make it so if column 4 is either a 0 or an NA, then remove the whole row? So in the example below only row 1 would be left.

```
Column 1   Column 2  Column 3 Column 4
 11            24        234    2123
 45            63        22      0
 234           234       123     NA
```

Comment: See tidyr::drop_na()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!is.na(Column.4) & Column.4 != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical vectors to subset your data:

```r
df[!is.na(df[,4]) & (df[,4]!=0), ]
```

Example:

```r
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(30), y = rnorm(30), z = rnorm(30), a = rep(c(0,1,NA),10))
             x          y           z a
2  -0.21772820 -0.5337648 -1.07579623 1
5   0.64536474  0.2011776 -0.12981424 1
8   2.36411372  0.0343823  2.03561701 1
11  1.09103526 -1.9287689  0.59511269 1
14  0.32482389 -0.5562136 -0.38943092 1
17  0.63621067 -1.6517097 -0.09804529 1
20  2.61892085  1.5575784 -0.50803567 1
23  0.07854647  1.1861483 -0.49798074 1
26  0.19561725  1.1036331 -0.66349688 1
29  0.22470875 -0.4192745  0.09153176 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to loop thru each row and it will display the rows the rows that satisfy the underlying conditions:

```
df[sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) all(!is.na(df[i,])) & all(df[i,] != 0)), ]
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Column.1 = c(11L, 45L, 234L), Column.2 = c(24L, 
63L, 234L), Column.3 = c(234L, 22L, 123L), Column.4 = c(2123L, 
0L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) -> df
```

Output:

```
# Column.1 Column.2 Column.3 Column.4
# 1       11       24      234     2123
```